# SQLite - Selects my rows, but they are not displayed / empty sqlite rows

Tags: sql, linq, sqlite

As Visual Studio extension I use **SQL Server Compact Toolbox** in the current version 4.7.632. I have a problem with a simple query of my SQLite database. I start the query via the SQLite browser of my extension.

1st query:

```
SELECT * FROM [statistics]

Id articlename category
1  article-1   A
2  article-2   B
3  article-3   C

(3 rows found)
```

2nd query:

```
SELECT id, articlename, category FROM [statistics]

Id articlename category
1  article-1
2  article-2
3  article-3

(3 rows found)
```

My second column "Category" is found but is left empty in this query. I only have this case if I explicitly list the two columns (articlename and category) instead of * in my query.

3rd query:

```
SELECT id, category FROM [statistics]

Id category
1
2
3

(3 rows found)
```

Why are the values not displayed for my category?The column is created within my database as "text, not null". Same as my column of the article.

Comment: As the problem is most likely with the VS extension, can you provide the VS code as well?  Everything works as expected in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/83598/2)

Comment: What's your table definition? You're using a sql server style identifier escape for the table name for some reason (not needed, and normal SQL style is to use double quotes anyways)... I bet you did the same with your columns in the definition and put a space in the column name (edit: or would that generate an error for an unknown column? Not at a computer right now to test)

Comment: My table definition: `CREATE TABLE [STATISTICS] (
  [Id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL
, [articlename] text NOT NULL
, [category] text NOT NULL`
);

Comment: With another tool I can read out the database completely.

Answer (score 1):

I have now used another SQL browser, here I got the columns displayed correctly - two fields were swapped. Strange that my VS Add-On *SQL Server Compact Toolbox* displays the column correctly.

Thank you so much for your help. I can recommend this SQLite browser to you https://sqlitebrowser.org/

I can tell you to look at the tables additionally via an independent tool from VS :)